# Ibus systray icon won't disappear

Tags: indicator

I'm on ubuntu 10.10 and when I uncheck the "show icon on system tray icon" on the ibus setup window, it disappears without a problem. But after reboot, the icon reappears on notification bar, even if the option above is unchecked. I even checked gconf, but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem : click on the icon, «*Settings*», check and uncheck «*Show icon on systray*».

(The [gconf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) key is : `/desktop/ibus/panel/show_icon_on_systray`)

This is really a bug, because it appear on startup while the key is set to false.

You can execute this in a script, at startup for instance :

```
gconftool --type boolean -s /desktop/ibus/panel/show_icon_on_systray true
gconftool --type boolean -s /desktop/ibus/panel/show_icon_on_systray false
```

Comment: (my script is very ugly)

Answer (score 1):

System > Preferences > Startup Applications > Startup Programs > Add

Name: Ibus

Command: ibus-daemon -rd

Comment: Hide ibus icon.

Add

Answer (score 0):

Its not designed to be disappeared. If you don't need it, you shall remove it through Software Center.

Comment: Or select another input method in method selection dialog

Comment: How do I remove it completely? (What's its name?)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, so obviously this is a bug on your system. You can try running ubuntu-bug ibus or ubuntu-bug ibus-daemon (I might have gotten the name of the ubuntu-bug process wrong, so if I did, you can go straight to launchpad.net).

The folks on launchpad will help you determine if there is a problem with your system, or if it is just a built in bug in the code that was overlooked.

Comment: Thanks but yesterday I installed mint 10 and I have the same problem again. Thinking a little bit, I came up with a solution though. I added killall ibus-daemon to startup, and then made a script which launces ibus-daemon again with a 5 seconds delay. Now the icon remains hidden as it should be. I guess the bug was in my autostart session.

Comment: ahhh. youshould report a bug on launchpad though.